# .htaccess rewrite help for wordpress permalink change

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I need some help with an `.htaccess` rewrite.

I have a site that had this permalink:
`/archive/%post_id`

and changed it to this:
`/%postname%/`

I have tried every single permalink redirect and change plugin - none of them work for this scenario.

The site has 15,000 posts, adding one line 301 redirects in the `.htaccess` file isn't going to work.

Can someone help me add a rewrite that will redirect all instances of `/archive/%post_id` to `/%postname%/` ?

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you tried all the plugins, but just in case, did you try this one:

http://www.shoutmeloud.com/how-to-use-deans-permalink-migration-plugin-for-wordpress.html

Looks like it dynamically creates 301s for you without SEO damage. Written in 2006, still working in 2009 - you might be able to tweak the code to get it working how you want.

If that is the 'quick' solution then the 'long' solution would be to write an app to lookup the `postname` by `postid` in your mysql db and then change each post URL in your wordpress database with the `postname` value.